# Why won't this be in order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called `acts_as_follower`(https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

Then I have a column called `last_active_at` in users table(User model)

Here, I want to fetch all the users who are followed by current_user.
and It has to be ordered by `last_active_at`

I tried this, but it was not in order.
How can I fix?

**controller**

```
@users = current_user.following_users(order: 'users.last_active_at DESC')
@users_followed = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3, you can use arel interface:

```
@users = current_user.following_users.order('users.last_active_at DESC')
```

Comment: please wait 8more mins so that I'll make your one as a best answer